# Invalid index "prompts" (in base "Array") in GDScript

Tags: gdscript

```
extends Control
var player_words = []
var template = [
    {
        "prompts": ["a name", "a noun", "adverb","adject"],
        "story":"Habia una vez tres mosqueteros %s, %s, %s y %s"
    },
    {
        "prompts": ["a name", "a noun", "adverb","adject"],
        'story':"Habia una vez tres mosqueteros %s, %s, %s y %s"
    },
    {
        "rompts": ["a name", "a noun", "adverb","adject"],
        "story":"Habia una vez tres mosqueteros %s, %s, %s y %s"
    },
    {
        "prompts": ["a name", "a noun", "adverb","adject"],
        "story":"Habia una vez tres mosqueteros %s, %s, %s y %s"
    }
]

var current_story
@onready
var PlayerText = $VBoxContainer/HBoxContainer/LineEdit
@onready
var Displaytext = $VBoxContainer/Label
@onready
var Butlabel = $VBoxContainer/HBoxContainer/Label2

func _ready():
    pick_current_story()

    Displaytext.text = "Bienvenidoooo "
    check_player_words_lenght()
    PlayerText.grab_focus()

func pick_current_story():
    randomize()
    current_story = template[randi() % template.size()]

func _on_line_edit_text_submitted(new_text):
    add_to_player_words()

func _on_texture_button_pressed():
    if is_story_done():
        get_tree().reload_current_scene()
    else:
        add_to_player_words()

func add_to_player_words():
    player_words.append(PlayerText.text)
    Displaytext.text = ""
    PlayerText.clear()
    check_player_words_lenght()

func is_story_done():
    return player_words.size() == template.prompts.size()

func check_player_words_lenght():
    if is_story_done():
        end_game()
    else:
        prompt_player()

func tell_story():
    Displaytext.text = template.story % player_words

func prompt_player():
    Displaytext.text += "May I Have" + template.prompts[player_words.size()] + "please"

func end_game():
    PlayerText.queue_free() 
    Butlabel.text = "Again"
    tell_story()
```

[image: Debugger screenshot]

In `is_story_done` I get the following error:

> Invalid get index 'prompts' (in base 'Array')

I am trying to make this code work.
The code should print the text inside of the randomly selected story from the `template` dictionary. The problem seems to be in the dictionary because when getting the "prompt" it doesn't recognize the text `your text`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because in your code you're trying to access a `prompts` property on your `template` array and an array does not have this property. It seems to me that what you actually want is get the corresponding property of your `current_story`, i. e in `is_story_done` you want to check if the amount of entered `player_words` is equal to the amount of `prompts` the story has.